# How do you add/specify predefined macros for GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

important thing: `-D` does not apply here.

Is it possible to declare macros that appear in every compilation (much like predefined macros) in some dynamic manner (meaning I'm lazy to recompile gcc)? or do I have to recompile my gcc? Should I have to recompile, how do I specify my predefined macros?

Comment: @Pyjong: please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: Until you can explain *why* you <del>need</del> want this, you're unlikely to get good answers that address your needs.  Can you explain why using `-D` doesn't achieve what you need?  Are you targeting a new platform, for instance?  (Or a new variant of an existing platform)  Are you trying to build some uncooperative source you don't want to change?  Are you simply trying to understand how GCC initialises itself?  Any of these are valid reasons to be interested, but they all make for very different answers.

Comment: @TobySpeight I do not agree. I like the answers bellow. And yes, new platform.

Comment: If you're targeting a new platform, you'll need to (create and) edit its spec file.  I suggest you [edit] your question to indicate that this is what you're trying to achieve, to avoid contributors wasting their time with answers that are not appropriate to this more specific question.

Comment: @Toby Ok that's what I got in one of the answers. Please be honest and admit the only reason for time wasted here is everyone boo-hooing about not knowing how to do it. Except for you and Basile, the two who actually told me how to do it.

Comment: Without additional motivations I voted to close that question as unclear. It surely is some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Why, I will accept your answer once I make it work..

Comment: @Pyjong, please don't accuse people of dishonesty, especially when we're trying to help improve your question so that it's useful for more readers than just yourself.  I'm leaving this question now.

Comment: @TobySpeight Ok, I am sorry I didn't mean to be rude. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider providing some (or improving yours) [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

You could patch the [`gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.c` file](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-7-branch/gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.c) of the source code of GCC.

You could [code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) then [use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) a GCC plugin defining additional predefined macros.

But I am sure it is a **very bad idea**; I recommend instead passing *explicitly* some `-D` flag to your compiler; your question smells badly as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You need to *motivate your question*.

You could instead organize your [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and add appropriately some `gcc` shell script adding that `-DMACRO` option and explicitly invoking e.g. `/usr/bin/gcc` with it.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to try this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you are wrong in trying this. Just add appropriately your `gcc` script and have a good `$PATH` using it. Could you please *improve your question* by motivating it appropriately (so add a few paragraphs explaining your motivations).

Comment: Ok, no. On closer look I do agree with you that what you're suggesting is wrong. Answer I was looking for is in gcc\config. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can

- use an alias:

  ```sh
  alias gcc="gcc -DMACRO1 -DMACRO2"
  ```
- Copy old `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc.original`. Make your own shell script and name it `/usr/bin/gcc`, inside which you have

  ```sh
  exec /usr/bin/gcc.original -DMACRO1 -DMACRO2 "$@"
  ```

Comment: There is no need to move `/usr/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc.original`. Just add an appropriate `gcc` shell script (and have a well ordered `$PATH`)